# CakePHP migration re-organising column order

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I have added new column using migrations.

This is my new added field

```
$table->addColumn('lastname', 'string', [
            'default' => null,
            'limit' => 255,
            'null' => false,
]);
```

This column added after `modified` field. I want to change column order and want to put it after column `name`. How can I do it using migrations ?

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @ndm I am using Mysql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `after` in `option`, In adding time

```
$table->addColumn('firstname', 'string', [
            'default' => null,
            'limit' => 255,
            'null' => false,
            'after' => 'name'
]);
```

Comment: You can't move where a column is. If you don't have any useful data in it yet, just roll back your migration, add the `after`, and run it again. If you have useful data, you'll need to add a new column where you want it, but with a different name, copy the data from the old column to the new, drop the old column, and rename the new one. Or do a `mysqldump` with `--complete-inserts`, edit the table create statement in the dump to rearrange the columns how you want, and re-import it.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Actually, you can, via `changeColumn()` ;)

Comment: Well, damn. Cool.

Comment: @ndm can we rename column name using changeColumn() ?

Comment: @NiloyRony Theoretically, yes, if you create a new column object (`\Phinx\Db\Action\ChangeColumn`) with a new name, and pass it as the second argument, but I'm not sure if that is auto-reversible, but it's much easier to simply use the [`renameColumn()`](https://book.cakephp.org/phinx/0/en/migrations.html#renaming-a-column) method anyways.

Comment: @ndm Before I have read https://book.cakephp.org/migrations/3/en/index.html this documentation and here no any advice for renameColumn,  Thanks for ref. this documentation.

Comment: @NiloyRony Yeah, the migrations plugin docs do not cover all of Phinx's functionality, but there's this one tiny, easy to be overlooked sentence that tells you that and encourages you to read the Phinx docs ;) It probably wouldn't hurt if that were a more prominent note.